# R : Using AND in grep on different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider below as data frame

```
test1 test2 test5
1a     dsa    xx
1c     ad     xxxx
1e     as     cccxx
2f     ssa    xxxxx
2a     bs     xxxx
2s     bs     xxzzx
```

I want to create a Subset which has "1" in test1 and "a" in test2, like the below one

```
test1 test2 test5
1a     dsa    xx
1c     ad     xxxx
1e     as     cccxx
```

I tried the following method

```
test4 = (test3[ grep("1", test3$test1),] & test3[ grep("a", test3$test2),])
```

but does not work

Comment: how about `dplyr::filter(df, test1 == 1, test2 == 'a')`?

Comment: or `df[df$test1 == 1 & df$test2 == "a", ]`

Comment: @ Psidom and @J_F both the methods work perfect

Comment: Do we have any way to use grep in there as my original data set has multiple characters on both test1 and test2. or some thing like "like" in SQL

Comment: You can use `%like%` from `data.table`. `setDT(df);df[test1 %like% "^1" & test2 %like% "^a"]`

Comment: @ytk. It worked. Thanks